# Representing table matrix data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

Is there any way to represent the output data below in JavaScript? I should also be able to retrieve these values.
I WANT THE OUTPUT OF THIS CODE TO BE REPRESENTED IN JAVASCRIPT.
It has nothing todo with the HTML code. I just used this HTML table to represent my data as I was not able to insert the image.

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>USD</td>
    <td>EUR</td>
    <td>INR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>USD</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>9124</td>
    <td>121</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EUR</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>INR</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>32</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const table = {
  USD: [32, 9124, 121],
  EUR: [43, 54, 23],
  INR: [32, 43, 32],
};

Object.defineProperty(table, 'toString', {
  value: function() {
    return JSON.stringify([
        ['', ...Object.keys(this)],
        ...Object.entries(this).map(([k, v]) => [k, ...v])
      ])
      .replace(/\,\[/g, ',\n[')
      .replace(/\[\[/g, '[\n[')
      .replace(/\]\]/g, ']\n]');
  }
});

console.log(table.toString());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```